# Grill of car got knocked inwards - should I worry?

Tags: chevrolet, radiator

A poor pidgeon came off second-best to the front grille of my Chevrolet Kalos a few days ago - I had no desire of being rear-ended by the car that was following me too closely!

So the bottom of the grille got pushed in due to this calamity, to the point where I can see the bolt-heads and mounting-slots that were previously obscured by it.

Aesthetically it doesn't look great, but I don't mind that too much. I'm wondering if there might be a knock-on effect, that might lead to something more serious though.

Have I anything to worry about? I haven't [yet] detected any odd smells or sounds.

Answer (score 3):

If no leakage from the radiator and the A/C (if so equipped) is still working, there shouldn't be an issue. I would advise you to pull out any broke broken pieces of grill as well as dead bird, to include feathers. The can get trapped in the radiator and reduce cooling efficiency. Get the grill portion replaced as soon as possible to help prevent some other road debris or animal from getting through there where it will ultimately cause damage to your radiator or A/C condenser.

Comment: I haven't noticed any such leakage, thankfully. Feathers etc have been removed, and from some fluke nothing seems to have broken - it just seems that the bottom got shunted in a bit. Thanks for your advice.